# Calculating SWR for a dipole

Tags: antenna, dipole, impedance-matching, bandwidth, math

I have a dipole wire antenna that is tuned to 14.0 MHz so that it has an SWR there of nearly 1:1. Is there a mathematical formula by which I can compute the expected SWR for other frequencies? I would, for example, like to calculate the expected SWR if I transmit a frequency of 14.3 MHz into that same antenna.

Comment: Welcome to this site, Bill! And thanks for a nice first question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a [great answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/6485/1550) to a similar question, "how do I calculate the bandwidth of an antenna".

> Assuming the antenna is in free space, you only need to know the length and diameter of the wire used to construct the dipole. The math is hairy but I wrote a program to do the calculations. Here is the SWR (assuming a 50 ohm source) and feedpoint impedance for a dipole 10 meters long, with a diameter of 2.053mm

And Phil shared the source of a Python program that will help calculate in the above linked answer.

Comment: Nice! I didn't recognize from the title that answer would include SWR. Thanks!